# Hough transform algorithm - Idiomatic c++

Tags: c++, image

I've got some working code to compute the Hough transform for circles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int *** allocate3DArray(int y, int x, int r)  {
    int ***array = (int***)malloc(sizeof(int**)*y);
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)  {
        array[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*x);
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)  {
            array[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*r);
            for(int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                array[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;

}

void free3d(int ***arr, int y, int x, int r)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)  {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)  {
            free(arr[i][j]);
        }
        free(arr[i]);

    }
    free(arr);

}

vector<Circle> HoughTransformCircles(Mat image, Mat &gradient_mag, Mat &gradient_dir)  {
    //Maximum circle radius is rLen = image.width / 2
    int rLen = image.rows/2;
    int ***houghSpace = allocate3DArray(image.rows, image.cols, rLen);
    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < rLen; r++)     {
                int x0 = x - (int)(r*cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
                int y0 = y - (int)(r*sin(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
                if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                    houghSpace[y0][x0][r]++;
                }
                x0 = x + (int)(r*cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
                y0 = y + (int)(r*sin(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
                if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                    houghSpace[y0][x0][r]++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    vector<Circle> circles;
    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)    {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)  {
            for (int r = 0; r < rLen; r++)  {
                if (houghSpace[y][x][r] > 30)  {
                    Circle temp  = Circle(x, y, r);
                    circles.push_back(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    free3d(houghSpace, image.rows, image.cols, rLen);

   return circles;
}
```

How do I make this as idiomatic as possible? I am not allowed to use C++ 11  unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add a link to a description of the Hough transform algorithm? If the restriction on C++11 is a teacher/professor mandated restriction could you please add the homework tag as well.

Comment: @pacmaninbw hasn't the homework tag been deprecated for quite some time?

Comment: @Casey not that I know of on Code Review.

Comment: @Casey I have just searched code review meta, it is not depreciated.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yeah, my mistake, I was thinking SO.

Comment: What is the reason for the "not allowed to use C++11?"

Comment: Your #1 priority for improving your code is to get rid of the array of arrays of arrays, and allocate the Hough space as a single block of memory. Using a `std::vector<int>` or a `cv::Mat` or whatever else you choose. Having the data spread out through memory and needing so many pointer lookups for each bin increment is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for improving the code.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses `vector` but doesn't include the corresponding header.  The code should have

```
#include <vector>
```

### Use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`

The difference between the two forms is that the former defines things within the `std::` namespace versus into the global namespace.  Language lawyers have lots of fun with this, but for daily use I'd recommend using `<cmath>` (and also `<cstdio>`).  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734230/math-interface-vs-cmath-in-c/8734292#8734292) for details.

### Avoid `malloc` and `free`

The old C-style calls still work, of course, but are not recommended.  They are error prone and tend to require more code to do correctly (i.e. checking the return value of `malloc` for `NULL`).  Instead, the modern C++ idiom is to use RAII which stand for "Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).  See [R.10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-mallocfree) and [R.1](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r1-manage-resources-automatically-using-resource-handles-and-raii-resource-acquisition-is-initialization) for details.

### Use objects

The 3D array would be much better implemented as an object.  While you could, of course, write one (and I'd encourage you to try that as a learning exercise), there's an even smarter way to do that in the next suggestion.

### Know your libraries

The code is already using the OpenCV `Mat` class, so what would make sense would be to also use that for the Hough space as well.  So this line:

```
int ***houghSpace = allocate3DArray(image.rows, image.cols, rLen);
```

would be written instead like this:

```
int dims[] = { image.rows, image.cols, rLen };
Mat houghSpace(3, dims, CV_8UC(1), Scalar::all(0));
```

Since that's a properly designed C++ class, it will automatically allocate memory as needed and also de-allocate it when the `houghSpace` object's destructor is called.  Using it is almost a simple:

```
houghSpace.at<cv::Vec3i>(y0,x0)[r]++;
```

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor code quality, so eliminating them should be a priority.  In this code, `gradient_mag` in `HoughTransformCircles` and `r` in `free3d` are unused. Your compiler is probably also smart enough to tell you that, if you ask it to do so.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It also appears you've got `using namespace cv;` somewhere as well and it's also not a good idea for similar reasons.

### Use variables to clarify your code

The code currently has this nested set of loops:

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rLen; r++)     {
            int x0 = x - (int)(r*cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
            int y0 = y - (int)(r*sin(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
            if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                houghSpace[y0][x0][r]++;
            }
            x0 = x + (int)(r*cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
            y0 = y + (int)(r*sin(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)));
            if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                houghSpace[y0][x0][r]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, I'd write it like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rLen; r++)     {
            int a = r * std::cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x));
            int b = r * std::sin(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x));
            int x0 = x - a;
            int y0 = y - b;
            if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                houghSpace.at<cv::Vec3i>(y0,x0)[r]++;
            }
            x0 = x + a;
            y0 = y + b;
            if(x0 >= 0 && x0 < image.cols && y0 >= 0 && y0 < image.rows )  {
                houghSpace.at<cv::Vec3i>(y0,x0)[r]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In C++11, I'd use a range-for.

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.

### Use `const` where possible

The `HoughTransformCircles` routine does not  alter the `image` passed to it, and so it should be declared as taking `const Mat& image` as an argument.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what was mentioned in the review by @nivag.

With the exception of the use of `std::vector` the code looks a lot more like C than any version of C++.

### Proper Include Headers

The code under review does not require `stdio.h`.

Please note that in C++ C programming include files can be included by inserting `'c'` before the header name and removing the dot h.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
```

### Lack Of Error Checking

In C++ the `new` operator has replaced the call to `malloc(size_t size)`, and the `delete` operator has replaced the call to `free(void *object)`. One of the benefits of the `new` operator is that it throws an exception when the memory allocation fails, the call to `malloc(size_t size)` only returns `NULL` (in C) or `nullptr` (in C++). Accessing memory through a null pointer causes unknown behavior, the return value of `malloc(size_t size)` should always be checked before usage.

```
int *** allocate3DArray(int y, int x, int r)  {
    int ***array = (int***)malloc(sizeof(int**)*y);
    if (array == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "In allocate3DArray allocation of array failed\n";
        return array;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)  {
        array[i] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*x);
        if (array[i] == nullptr)
        {
            std::cerr << "In allocate3DArray allocation of array[" << i << "] failed\n";
            return nullptr;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)  {
            array[i][j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*r);
            if (array[i][j] == nullptr)
            {
                std::cerr << "In allocate3DArray allocation of array[" << i << "][" << j <<  "] failed\n";
                return nullptr;
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                array[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

For the reasons listed above, `new` should be preferred over `malloc`.

### Use C++ Container Classes over C Style Arrays

As mentioned in another review there are clear benefits of using C++ Container Classes over C Style Arrays. In addition to the proper type of memory being allocated with less code, container classes provide iterators which provide safer ways to iterate through the objects in the container, it is much more difficult to iterate off the end of an array when the iterators and container.begin() and container.end() are used.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things I would change here:

- `gradient_mag` is unused in HoughTransformCircles and should be removed.
- `Mat` will presumably normally be a relatively large array so relatively expensive to copy, additionally you don't modify `image` or `gradient_dir` in the code. These can both be passed in as `const Mat &`.
- You should make variables that shouldn't change e.g. `rLen`, const. This prevents you accidentally modifying them later.
- Similarly you should prefer `size_t` to int for variables that can't be <0. In your case all the counters in the loops and rLen.
- Avoid c style casts e.g. `(int)(r*cos(gradient_dir.at<double>(y, x)`, prefer explicit `static_cast<int>()` instead. The c style cast will do a const cast or re-interpret cast if it thinks it needs to which can lead to unexpected results if you are not careful.
- I would avoid using c style arrays to store `houghSpace`. What you have done looks correct, but would be easy to break if you want to extend the code.
  In modern c++ the obvious replacement for this is std::array, but if you are not using c++11 that is not an option.
  Another option is to use std::vector. You can initialise the vector to zeros of the desired size. This option might have some memory overhead, but it should be small (would need testing).
  A third option as you are already using opencv would be to make houghSpace another Mat. I'm not sure what the memory/performance characteristics of Mat are, but this seems like the natural solution.

Comment: If the user can't use `std::array`, then they certainly can't use `std::vector` which they are already doing.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: actually, `std::array` was new in C++11, but `std::vector` existed in C++98, so nivag's answer is correct.